# Which solana wallet is easiest to dev on?

Tags: wallet

Easiest here I mean with adequate tutorials and tech support (meaning most people code on the wallet). Will that be phantom or solflare or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Solana wallet adapter in my opinion is what you want. It supports popular wallets out of the box.
https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter

Comment: But this adapter is in TypeScript. I'm using vanilla JS